# PayPal billing agreements REST API - how to start immediately

Tags: paypal

How can I start charging a user the user immediately for a PayPal billing agreement?

Here's what I've got so far.

1. Create a Billing Plan (POST .../payments/billing-plans/)
2. Make it active (PATCH .../payments/billing-plans/)
3. Create a Billing Aggreement (POST .../payments/billing-agreements/)
4. Send user to approval_url, user approves, redirected to return url
5. Execute agreement (POST .../payments/billing-agreements//agreement-execute)

This all seems to work, but I want to charge the user right now and every month in the future. If I set `start_date` to now in step 3 I get an error, it must be in the future. If I set it in the future the user is not charged.

Do I need to 'Set outstanding agreement amounts' then 'Bill outstanding agreement amounts' for the initial payment?

Also, what about monthly payments, do they require some action or do they just happen as specified in the Billing Plan?

---

**Update**

I'm testing this around `2014-09-16T20:06:30+0000`

If I send `start_date` as the current UTC time it get an error at step 2 telling me it must be in the future.

If I send the current date +30 secs or +2 hours I get through to step 5 which returns a 400 response: UNKNOWN_ERROR "An unknown error has occurred"

If I send the current date +4 hours it all works. The current UTC time is 8pm so adding 4 hours means the `start_date` is tomorrow.

Does this mean I can't charge the user today? Does the `start_date` have to be in next day or even the next *business* day?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've talked to a PayPal rep and found that `start_date` must be tomorrow or later. They are going to add this to the docs.

If you want to start monthly billing immediately you might be able to do it by setting the start date to be in one months time and charging a setup fee to cover the first month. I haven't tested this as it's not what I want.

Comment: I've now tested the setup fee option - it doesn't charge the user immediately either! It seems there's no way to do it at all.

Comment: They're such a mess. I also got an official response, they said 5 minutes in PST (contrary to what they told you). They've given me mixed info spanning multiple calls on just about every topic I've hit them with.

Comment: I see that from California, it charges immediately if I pass a charge before 16:00 (winter) which means UTC is still the same day. After 16:00, the UTC is on the following day and the charge does not go through immediately. It will within 8h, I assume (PST is UTC - 8). So PayPal has a huge time problem with their plans.

Comment: The paypal sandbox has issues regarding initial payment amounts not working.  However, this does appear to work as expected on the live environment.

Comment: Whenever I create an agreeement, it sets the agreement start date 7 hours later and I cannot check the payment.

Comment: I have similar problem while dealing with paypal subscription which is I cannot use the default start_time which is current datetime, get idea from this similar problem solution and give a value few minutes after then problem solved

Answer (score 2):

First payment for agreements will be billed right on specified start_date.  The subsequent amounts are also taken automatically by PP. You need to work with the BillOutstandingAmount calls only if PP failed to pick the payment on the renewal date.

The problem I faced when developing with their RestAPI was specifying a wrong timezone.  Maybe this is the same for you. Make sure the proper timezone is specified in your start_date (with all dates given to PP in fact)

Dates should be in this format:  yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ

ex. start_date = 2014-09-16T09:20:00**-0400**

IF you want to make sure Paypal accepts the date as being valid, just add a few seconds to it.

Let's say you are in Java, you can do something like:

```
private String getPaypalDate()
{
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ");

    // Add 30 seconds to make sure Paypal accept the agreement date
    Date rightNow = new Date(new Date().getTime() + 30000);

    return df.format(rightNow);
}
```

Comment: It works if I add 1 day to the `start_date`. A few seconds doesn't work, even a few hours doesn't work. Is there no way to bill immediately?

Comment: You sure you use the correct timezone?  I doubt it would work for me and not for you.  If you specify current datetime, by the time your user accept the agreement it will bill right away when you execute it.

Comment: Strange, I've done some more testing. Please see the update in the question.

Comment: @Ethorsen Does the transaction charge the account? Mine goes through, and shows "Active", but no charge.

Answer (score 1):

I used this date format working.

```
  $time = time();
  $startDate = date('Y-m-d\\TH:i:s\\Z', $time);
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't replicate, actually. I stumbled on this thread when getting the error due to setting it to `moment.now()`. But setting it to even 5 seconds in the future works a-ok. I'm using JavaScript, `"start_date": moment().add({seconds:5}).format()` and that checks out fine. Moment.js will set TZ to UTC when formatting as such, so it's gotta be a timezone thing on your end?

Comment: I've been struggling with this too. When I set it a few second ahead, it goes through and it shows as "Active" in the account, but it doesn't actually charge anything... Alternatively, if I set an initial cost, it goes through but sets the status to "Pending". I'm 100% sure my timezone is set correctly.

Comment: I've gotten an official response: "The best workaround to make the recurring payment as immediate is by adding 5 minutes earlier from current time. If using a few seconds, it might be issue later if any network breaking on server or client side.Also make sure you use PST as the time because PayPal system is saving any try in PST time zone."

Comment: Do we have to use PST or GMT? Because paypal says to use ISO 8601 format.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the payments just process based on the date being before or after 07:00 UTC of the current date.

For example. The current date time is 2017-05-04T04:50:00.00Z I set my start date to be the current UTC date time plus 30 seconds. Because the agreement date is set to a value greater then the current date time the API doesn't throw an error, but it DOESN'T set your time to be what you specified. Instead it sets it to 2017-05-04T07:00:00Z.

Now, if you have the same date time of 2017-05-04T04:50:00.00Z and instead of adding 30 seconds you add 24hrs you'd think that your time would then be set to be 2017-05-05T04:50:00.00Z. But no, the time will be set to 2017-05-05T07:00:00Z.

So it seems like these just process everyday at 07:00 UTC and you can't specify anything but the date.