# Paypal billing agreement does not pay quickly?

Tags: paypal

I've made a Paypal plan like the following, at 49$ :

```
{
    'id': 'P-PAYPAL-ID',
    'name': "My Plan",
    'description': 'My description of the plan',
    'type': 'INFINITE',
    'merchant_preferences': {
        'auto_bill_amount': 'YES',
        "initial_fail_amount_action": "CONTINUE",
        "max_fail_attempts": "3",
        "return_url": "https://example.com/paypal/response",
        "cancel_url": "https://example.com/paypal/response"
    },
    'payment_definitions': [{
        'name': 'Monthly payment',
        'type': 'REGULAR',
        'frequency': 'MONTH',
        'frequency_interval': 1,
        'cycles': 0,
        'amount': {
            'value': '49',
            'currency': 'USD'
        }
    }]
}
```

I've created the plan and enabled it following the [documentation here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments.billing-plans/#plan_create).

Then I created a [Billing Agreement](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments.billing-agreements) by following the steps :

1. Create the billing agreement
2. Redirect the user to the Paypal page to accept the agreement
3. Execute the agreement from the URL I got in 1.

Everything works fine, in my sandbox user account, I can see the "Recurring payment details" marked as Active.

I subscribed my server to the webhooks.

**My problem is the following** : The payment is not done immediately? I've waited an hour, and nothing is paid!

Is there a request I forgot to make to "execute the executed agreement"...?

Comment: See my response on this question.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25858816/paypal-billing-agreements-rest-api-how-to-start-immediately

Answer (score 0):

The short and sweet answer is that it's not possible. Within the agreement you have the option to set a startDate value. Based on my experience the below statement is what I've concluded.

It looks like the payments just process based on the date being before or after 07:00 UTC of the current date.

For example. The current date time is 2017-05-04T04:50:00.00Z I set my start date to be the current UTC date time plus 30 seconds. Because the agreement date is set to a value greater then the current date time the API doesn't throw an error, but it DOESN'T set your time to be what you specified. Instead it sets it to 2017-05-04T07:00:00Z.

Now, if you have the same date time of 2017-05-04T04:50:00.00Z and instead of adding 30 seconds you add 24hrs you'd think that your time would then be set to be 2017-05-05T04:50:00.00Z. But no, the time will be set to 2017-05-05T07:00:00Z.

So it seems like these just process everyday at 07:00 UTC and you can't specify anything but the date.